# How to test if Mock function was called (pytest)

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

There is an abstract class for variables. It has a `_callbacks` method for executing functions provided by a controller class, whenever value changed. I want to write a test for it.

```
from unittest.mock import Mock


class Variable():

    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
        self.callbacks = {}

    def add_callback(self, func):
        self.callbacks[func] = None

    def _callbacks(self):
        for func in self.callbacks:
            func(self.value)


def test_var_add_callback():
    func = Mock()
    var = Variable()
    var.add_callback(func)
    var._callbacks()
    assert func.assert_called()
```

Using pytest gets this:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ test_var_add_callback ____________________________

    def test_var_add_callback():
        func = Mock()
        var = Variable()
        var.add_callback(func)
        var._callbacks()
>       assert func.assert_called()
E       AssertionError: assert None
E        +  where None = <bound method NonCallableMock.assert_called of <Mock id='2389330693592'>>()
E        +    where <bound method NonCallableMock.assert_called of <Mock id='2389330693592'>> = <Mock id='2389330693592'>.assert_called

tests\test_stack.py:25: AssertionError
===================== 1 failed, 18 passed in 0.40 seconds =====================
```

I can't understand why it isn't working. I read this [Understanding the Python Mock Object Library #Assertions and Inspection](https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/#assertions-and-inspection) and I'm pretty sure I'm doing same things as in the example. Moreover, assertion returns `None` even if I call `func` manually

```
def test_var_add_callback():
    func = Mock()
    var = Variable()
    var.add_callback(func)
    var._callbacks()
    func()
    assert func.assert_called()
```

Please help me find what am I missing.

Comment: `s/assert func.assert_called()/func.assert_called()`. `assert_called()` will invoke the assertion under the hood, failing if the mocked function was not called.

Comment: Also, assertion doesn't return anything. It raises an `AssertionError` if the condition is not fullfilled, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `assert` keyword before `func.assert_called()` statement.

`func.assert_called()` returns `None`, `assert None` will raise an `AssertionError`.